# How to extract line from txt file into a label?

Tags: vb.net, label, extract

I've looked everywhere but it all confuses me, can you please help? And tell me what everything is and does? I dont know my programing language, how do i find out?

```
Sub ReadFile()

    Dim oFSO As New System.Object
    Dim oFS
    oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\Users\Public\repomaker.txt")
    Label1 = oFS.ReadLine
End Sub
```

that was my most recent attempt! Can someone make it easier?

Comment: Which version of `vb`? VB 6 or VB.NET?

Comment: I am sure you've tried at least one or two of these confusing things. Could you post your most recent attempt? We'll gladly fix it for you.

Comment: @CodyGray how do i find that?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i have updated the question for you

Comment: Uh, start with Help -> About in your programming environment and we can figure it out from there. It'll say either "Visual Basic 6" or "Visual Studio xxxx". From the code you just posted, it looks like VB 6, but I've seen people write VB 6 code in VB.NET...

Comment: Hmm, then your code is definitely wrong. You're using VB.NET, which is the new version. VB 6 is the old version from about 1998, which looks like what you're writing. Are you learning from a very old book or sample code online? Make sure you get a new book specifically about VB.NET or Visual Basic 2010, or you'll waste a lot of time. No wonder it's confusing!

Comment: @CodyGray i search online for these codes, can i use something like instr?

Comment: No, that's all VB 6 stuff. The .NET Framework provides a whole new way of doing things. The old stuff is not going to compile anymore. It's best to think of VB 6 and VB.NET as completely different languages. Sites like http://www.vb6.us/ and http://www.vbtutor.net/vb6/vbtutor.html are not going to be helpful, just confusing and wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6732/discussion-between-user1081679-and-cody-gray)

Comment: You can use the [File.ReadLines-Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) to read all lines in a File.

Comment: @TimSchmelter how can i harness this method in my case?

Comment: @user: In one line: `Label1.Text = IO.File.ReadLines("C:\Users\Public\repomaker.txt").FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last attempt was very close - here is one way to fix it:

```
Sub ReadFile()
    Dim oFS As StreamReader = File.OpenText("c:\Users\Public\repomaker.txt")
    Label1.Text = oFS.ReadLine
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to escape slashes in VB.NET. And the label controls in .NET don't automatically resolve to their default properties (or at least I don't *think* they do, and even if they do, you shouldn't rely on this).

Comment: i got an error on 'oFS.ReadLine' saying "Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Label".

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the corrections! I am not good with VB syntax, so I used an [online translator](http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/) to convert to C# and back. That's how the escapes got into the program.

Comment: thank the lord! it works a treat, thanks to both of you @CodyGray and dasblinkenlight